# How to put and retrieve parcelized objects using bundle and safeargs?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Navigation and stumble upon safeargs.
I encountered a problem which, based on my observation, has something to do with passing my custom object inside the bundle.

-used parcelable instead of serialization

-checked that I have same name for nav_graph xml arguments and the bundle key in which I pass it as putParcelable

Please check my code:

```
Inside my local headlines
newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { article ->

            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable("article", article)
                Log.d(TAG, "success ---- $article")
            }

            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_localHeadlinesFragment_to_articleFragment, bundle
            )
        }
```

Here's my article fragment:

```
class ArticleFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentArticleBinding
    val args : ArticleFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentArticleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val article = args.article

        //apply to webview

    }
}
```

When I tried to remove the bundle parameter in my findController.navigate function, it navigates properly so my assumption is that the passing of values is the problem.

Editted:
This is the error I am facing:

```
2022-04-28 10:34:25.592 9987-9987/com.fangzsx.news_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fangzsx.news_app, PID: 9987
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at com.fangzsx.news_app.model.Article.hashCode(Unknown Source:14)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.hashCode(NavBackStackEntry.kt:232)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.linkChildToParent(NavController.kt:144)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack(NavController.kt:1914)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack$default(NavController.kt:1809)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1717)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1715)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.push(NavController.kt:288)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:246)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:162)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:261)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1715)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1541)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1468)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1926)
        at com.fangzsx.news_app.ui.fragments.LocalHeadlinesFragment$onViewCreated$1.invoke(LocalHeadlinesFragment.kt:45)
        at com.fangzsx.news_app.ui.fragments.LocalHeadlinesFragment$onViewCreated$1.invoke(LocalHeadlinesFragment.kt:43)
        at com.fangzsx.news_app.adapters.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-3$lambda-2(NewsAdapter.kt:50)
        at com.fangzsx.news_app.adapters.NewsAdapter.$r8$lambda$uO6GOWfSmC-FltVST3LPazI9WMM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.fangzsx.news_app.adapters.NewsAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7866)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:550)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Adapter:

```
package com.fangzsx.news_app.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import coil.load
import com.fangzsx.news_app.databinding.NewsItemLayoutBinding
import com.fangzsx.news_app.model.Article

class NewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

    inner class ArticleViewHolder(val binding : NewsItemLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    var differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            NewsItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ),
                parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.binding.apply {
            tvTitle.text = "\"${article.title}\""
            tvDescription.text = article.description
            ivImage.load(article.urlToImage){
                crossfade(true)
                crossfade(1000)
            }

            btnReadMore.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let {
                    it(article)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var onItemClickListener : ((Article) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener : (Article) -> Unit){
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }


}
```

Article Class:

```
package com.fangzsx.news_app.model

import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize


@Entity(
    tableName = "articles"
)

@Parcelize
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val description: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val source: Source,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: That error indicates that the exception is thrown from `com.fangzsx.news_app.model.Article.hashCode(Unknown Source:14)` - that's your code, not Navigation's code. Please include your `Article` class.

Comment: I eddied and attached my Article Class. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what is your issue because you didn't describe it. As I read through, your code should be working fine. And for your issue I assume that your Article class didn't implement `Parcelable` that cause the app to crashes.

Fix it by implementing `Parcelable` interface in your Article class or you can use `kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize` annotation.

In your app level build.gradle:

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
...
```

Your Article class:

```
@Parcelize
data class Article(val title: String) : Parcelable
```

When you use Safe Args you can navigate to a destination with a generated Directions class:

```
val direction = LocalHeadlinesFragmentDirections.actionLocalHeadlinesFragmentToArticleFragment(article)
findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

And your `navigation.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_local_headlines">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_local_headlines"
        android:name="...LocalHeadLine"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_local_headlines">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_localHeadlinesFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_article" />
    </fragment

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_article"
        android:name="...ArticleFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_article" >
        <argument
            android:name="article"
            app:argType="...Article" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

As per the doc:

> After enabling Safe Args, your generated code contains the following
> type-safe classes and methods for each action as well as with each
> sending and receiving destination.
>
> A class is created for each destination where an action originates.
> The name of this class is the name of the originating destination,
> appended with the word "Directions". For example, if the originating
> destination is a fragment that is named SpecifyAmountFragment, the
> generated class would be called SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.
>
> This class has a method for each action defined in the originating
> destination.
>
> For each action used to pass the argument, an inner class is created
> whose name is based on the action. For example, if the action is
> called confirmationAction, the class is named ConfirmationAction. If
> your action contains arguments without a defaultValue, then you use
> the associated action class to set the value of the arguments.
>
> A class is created for the receiving destination. The name of this
> class is the name of the destination, appended with the word "Args".
> For example, if the destination fragment is named
> ConfirmationFragment, the generated class is called
> ConfirmationFragmentArgs. Use this class's fromBundle() method to
> retrieve the arguments.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I updated my post and included my error log.

Comment: My app crashes the moment I click a button to send the article into the fragment. I can print the Article data class's field in log. But upon sending, it crash.

Comment: @JayGarzon Your code above is correctly implemented and could be improve with the suggestion in my answer. But it seems that the `article` object is null. You can post your `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` code so that I can help you investigate more on this.

Comment: I attached my Adapter Class above. I think I dont face any issue with regards to grabbing the article itself for the reason that I can print the article's detail in my Log successfully. No idea why it return this null error upon using it with safe args.

Comment: @JayGarzon Your code looks fine. I can't say for sure what causes the issue. I think you will have to share the full code.